# SELECT and DELETE

Tags: java, mysql

I want to select the first row in a table, order by `time` (ascending), then delete that row. I don't want to use two queries since there's a possibility that another client could select that row before it gets deleted (there will be several machines connected at once from different networks).

I was thinking I could do something like

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` ORDER BY `time` LIMIT 1;
    DELETE FROM `mytable` ORDER BY `time` LIMIT 1
```

...but I got an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '; DELETE *
>   FROM `pending` ORDER BY `time` LIMIT
>   1' at line 1

What's the best way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re your error message (different than in your question):

```
DELETE * FROM pending ORDER BY time LIMIT 1
```

Looks like an error in your syntax. Try removing the `*`. That is,

```
DELETE FROM pending ORDER BY time LIMIT 1
```

Should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a temporary table, MySQL doesn't let you delete from a table that you are using, see this code:

```
insert  tmpTable
        (id)
select  id
from    YourTable yt
order by time limit 1;

delete  
from    YourTable
where   ID in (select id from tmpTable);
```

Comment: Does tmpTable need to be dropped later or..?

Comment: You don't need to create a temporary table explicitly. You can use a derived table `delete from YourTable where ID = (select id from (select id from YourTable order by time limit 1) t);`. But Riedsio's answer seems even better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sub-queries like.

```
delete from table where id in ( select id from table order by time limit 1);
```

Performance wise am not sure, how good is this solution. You might have to do a analyze and see how this works for you.